# Is git svn clone still performing work?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, svn2git

I'm running 'git svn clone' on a non-standard repository and it appears stuck somewhere in the process.  It did perform work on locating all of the branches and tags but when getting to a certain revision it has stopped outputting anything and has been utilizing 1 core of my CPU for approx 20 hours now.

The last line output is:

```
r2007 = f4ccc32aa2c1c504d7baca98a4efe628be3d6485 (refs/remotes/origin/MySVNRepo)
```

Is there any way of determining if it is still doing meaningful work or if it's futile to keep waiting?  Or even what might be causing it to be stuck?

I've tried running `du -s` on the `.git` folder but it doesn't seem to be changing size.

Comment: Is this about a one-time migration and you are only using Git afterwards, or do you want to commit back to SVN from your Git clone?

Comment: It's a one time migration, moving from SVN to Git

Answer (score 1):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but the right `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want and it is a gazillion faster.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)